# Electron require ipcRenderer not working

Tags: electron

I am trying to do a simple ipc.send and ipc.on but for some reason I am getting undefined on this electron require.

libs/custom-menu.js:

```
'use-strict';

const BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

exports.getTemplate = function () {
  const template = [
    {
      label: 'Roll20',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Player Handbook',
          click() {
            console.log('test');
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      label: 'View',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Toggle Fullscreen',
          accelerator: 'F11',
          click(item, focusedWindow) {
            if (focusedWindow) {
              focusedWindow.setFullScreen(!focusedWindow.isFullScreen());
            }
          },
        },
        {
          label: 'Toggle Developer Tools',
          accelerator: (function () {
            if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
              return 'Alt+Command+I';
            }
            return 'Ctrl+Shift+I';
          }()),
          click(item, focusedWindow) {
            if (focusedWindow) {
              focusedWindow.toggleDevTools();
            }
          },
        },
        {
          label: 'Reload',
          accelerator: 'F5',
          click() {
            BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().reloadIgnoringCache();
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      label: 'Random Generators',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'World Generator',
          click() {
            ipcRenderer.send('show-world');
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
  return template;
};
```

The error is 
cannot read property 'send' of undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `BrowserWindow` module is only available in the main process, the `ipcRenderer` module is only available in the renderer process, so regardless of which process you run this code in it ain't gonna work. I'm guessing since `ipcRenderer` is not available you're attempting to run this code in the main process.

Comment: hey, would u mind taking a look at [my very similar question here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53753181/webcontents-send-and-ipcrenderer-on-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer might have been too late for you but for  other

If you're trying access any of main process modules from renderer process you will need to go through remote module,

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote
```

see documentation [remote](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote)

Answer (score 0):

Just for those who can't get this to work in react app ipcRenderer or in any environment that requires preload file.

[preload setup](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-468323625)

Answer (score -1):

These lines worked for me:

```js
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-certificate-errors', 'true') 
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('allow-insecure-localhost', 'true')
```

Answer (score -2):

In the renderer process, the script tags that have the "require" statement needs to be:
`<script type="javascript"></script>`

Placing your call to require in a script tag without the type set doesn't work.