# Electron's event.sender.send doesn't send, or ipcRenderer doesn't recieve

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

This seems like it should be simple. I have a line in main.js that reads:

`event.sender.send("name-prompt")`

I know that this *is* being called, I got a warning when I tried to pass in `event`. Then in `index.js` I have

```
ipcRenderer.on("name-prompt", () => {
    console.log("why isn't this working")
    document.getElementById("details-prompt").classList.add("visibility-override")
})
```

And this just never runs. [webContents.send and ipcRenderer.on Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53753181/webcontents-send-and-ipcrenderer-on-not-working) uses webContents.send, which as I understand it is distinct from event.sender.send. I'm definitely very new to electron, so there's a lot I'm missing. What should I do to make this work?

Edit: full code for IPCMain.on

```
ipcMain.on("add-from-file-clicked", (event) => {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile'] }).then(result => {
        console.log(result.canceled);
        console.log(result.filePaths);

        if (!result.canceled) {
            event.sender.send("name-prompt")
        }
    })
})
```

And yes, I've verified that result.canceled is false. Thanks!

Comment: enable the `nodeIntegration` when you are creating `BrowserWindow` at your main.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60227586/ipcrenderer-not-receiving-message-from-main-process/60227981#60227981

Comment: @tpikachu I have nodeIntegration enabled, as I understand it require wouldn't even work if I didn't.

Comment: Let me see the ipcMain part that you are listening from the reneder

Comment: @tpikachu sure, thank you

Comment: Change this to `event.reply("name-prompt)`

Comment: @tpikachu ah sorry I'm an idiot. I checked my terminal instead of the console for the output, event.reply worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Should I post full answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ipcMain.on("add-from-file-clicked", (event) => {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile'] }).then(result => {
        console.log(result.canceled);
        console.log(result.filePaths);

        if (!result.canceled) {
            event.reply("name-prompt")
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to confirm that you are sending a message from index.js so that main.js can respond with event.sender.send().

There is an example using event.sender.send() in the main.js in the first two code blocks at http://www.atom.pe/docs/api/ipc-main/.
Maybe you could check your code against it.

Comment: Thank you, I am sending a message from index.js. I had no problems with that. That link is actually where I learned about event.sender.send.