# Passing contents of local file to renderer on Electron

Tags: electron

I'm trying to read a file on local disk in the main process and then send it's contents to renderer process. While the file reads correctly (as I see in main's console), the data is not received on renderer side for some reason.

I started just today and used this boilerplate https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate

Here is my code:
main.ts

```
  mainWindow.loadURL(resolveHtmlPath('index.html'));

  // I put reading file in a separate function with callback
  loadConfig('config.xml', (config) => {
    mainWindow?.webContents.send('config', config);
  });

  mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', () => {
```

utils.ts

```
export function loadConfig(
  configPath: string,
  sendConfig: (config: any) => void
) {
  if (fs.existsSync(configPath)) {
    fs.readFile(configPath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
      const parser = new XMLParser();
      const config = parser.parse(data);
      console.log(config);
**      sendConfig(config);
**    });
  }
```

Finally, here is my index.ts. I include it all since the boilerplate's code is working and my 'config' does not.

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const container = document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement;
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);

// calling IPC exposed from preload script
window.electron.ipcRenderer.once('ipc-example', (arg) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(arg);
});
window.electron.ipcRenderer.sendMessage('ipc-example', ['ping']);

// Nothing is logged
window.electron.ipcRenderer.on('config', (config) => {
  console.log('config');
});
```

You can find preload.ts in boilerplate's github if it's needed, I only added `export type Channels = 'ipc-example' | 'config';`  config here.

Comment: Which XMLParser class are you using? My guess is its `parse()` is async. BTW `loadConfig()` would be clearer if rewritten as an `async` function, using `await`; you could also drop using `fs.existsSync()` which will slow things down, and catch the fs.readFile() error (and swallow it) when it does not exist.

Comment: I'm using fast-xml-parser https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser , but it is not async as I know. Thank you for code suggestions, I will definitely follow them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, I've been able to encounter a very similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53753181/webcontents-send-and-ipcrenderer-on-not-working) of mine.

Solution is to wrap the loadConfig (or any of your code that sends something to renderer) into the

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', ()=>{
  // My loadConfig or your code
})
```